# Factory returning classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

Wrote a library that, depending on the input data; creates classes and uses them inside a main class.

To make the code more maintainable and readable, I've moved the class generation logic into a separate file that exports a factory function.

Code was written in ES2015. Now I'm migrating to TypeScript.

Here is a pseudo example:

#### factory.ts

```ts
export default function (foo:string) => {
    class A {
        value:string = foo + '-A';
    }

    return { A };
};
```

#### Main.ts

```ts
import factory from './factory';

export default class Main {
    private inner:any;
    constructor(foo:string) {
        this.inner = factory(foo);
    }
    get a() {
        return new this.inner.A();
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```ts
let main = new Main('bar');
console.log(main.a.value); // "bar-A"
```

#### Problems:

- TS compiler error:
  `Default export of the module has or is using private name 'A'.`
- Cannot define the type of the getter `a` as `A` in `Main` class (e.g. `get a():A { ... }`

How would you resolve this (keeping the factory classes in a separate file)? Or should I change the design pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like:

```
export interface Base {}

export interface IA extends Base {
    value: string;
}

export type Builders = {
    [name: string]: { new <T extends Base>(): T };
}

export function factory(foo: string): Builders {
    class A implements IA {
        value:string = foo + '-A';
    }

    return { A };
};
```

And:

```
import { factory, IA, Builders } from './Factory';

export default class Main {
    private inner: Builders;

    constructor(foo:string) {
        this.inner = factory(foo);
    }

    get a():IA {
        return new this.inner.A() as IA;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

What's wrong with this as `factory.ts`:

```
export class Base {}

export type Builders = {
    [name: string]: { new <T extends Base>(): T };
}

class A extends Base {
    value: string;

    constructor();
    constructor(foo: string);
    constructor(foo?: string) {
        super();
        this.value = foo + "-A";
    }
}

// more classes...

export function factory(foo: string): Builders {
    return { A: A.bind(A, foo) };
};
```

It's basically the same as what you did, just that the classes are not defined inside the class, and are exported so no need for the interfaces I suggested.
Also, this way all the classes will only be evaluated once and not every time the `factory` function is invoked.

Comment: Thanks this works. I need to additionally define interfaces for 4 classes, though.

Comment: You can't export the classes (as values nor types) if they are declared inside the function, but the compiler needs to have a type for it (other than using generic types) so you'll need to expose an interface per class. The question is why not to declare those classes in the module level? What benefits do you get from having them in the function?

Comment: I see. The only reason for the factory function is to move quite complex inner classes to another file so that the code is cleaner.

Comment: That's fine, but why don't you place the classes at the same level as the factory function (module level) and export them as well? Then you won't need the interfaces.

Comment: As in the example, `foo` is not passed to the inner/generated classes via constructor parameters. So they need to be in a factory function. Then I need to export the main class so that needs to be outside of the factory.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd have to define them within the constructor of the main class (or split logic into private methods) which makes it extra complex and ugly.

Comment: How is `foo` passed to class `A`?

Comment: This is it. Excellent. One last question; the overloads of the constructor.. Isn't `constructor(foo?:string)` enough? Other two overloads are essentially the same imho.

Comment: I prefer the explicit approach in these case. The point is that who ever is constructing the instances only use the constructor without the `foo` (as it's being "injected" with the `bind` function).

Comment: Also, if there are arguments that the ctor does need to get then you can't mark `foo` as optional because it has to stay the first param (because you bind it), so you'll need two different ctor overloads to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

Your code (the OP's) is working just fine in July 2019 with Typescript 3.5.2.

PS. I got here when I was trying to create a **Class Factory in Typescript**.

Things to keep in mind:

1. The concept of Class definition in Typescript has two folds.  One is *the instance type*, and the other one is *the constructor function*. ([source in TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions))
2. Since Typescript 2.8 [released in March 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v2.8.0), you can explicitly create the *instance type* from *the constructor function* using [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types). e.g. `type classType = InstanceType<typeof C>`.  This should make the explicit `type` definition in the selected answer simpler.
3. Finally, I got my code working using a simple trick as following:

```
export default class MyNewClass
   extends ClassFactory("custom param1") {}
```

This way I am actually defining the generated class as a new class by itself, so both the constructor function and the instance-type type are going to be implicitly created and will be valid.  And I don't need to explicitly define the two separately.

Comment: `InstanceType<typeof C>`  is a great find, but it does not work when C is an abstract class. In that case you can however use type `type classType = abstract new (...args: any) => C;`