# How to make an Object Factory maintaining the type

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

I have created the following object factory to instantiate implementations of all my interfaces:

```js
interface SomeInterface {
  get(): string;
}

class Implementation implements SomeInterface {
  constructor() {}
  get() {
    return "Hey :D";
  }
}

type Injectable = {
  [key: string]: () => unknown;
};

// deno-lint-ignore prefer-const
let DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS: Injectable = {
  SomeInterface: () => new Implementation(),
};

let MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS: Injectable = {};

class Factory {
  static getInstance(interfaceName: string, parameters: unknown = []) {
    if (MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS[interfaceName])
      return MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS[interfaceName]();
    return DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS[interfaceName]();
  }

  static mockWithInstance(interfaceName: string, mock: unknown) {
    MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS[interfaceName] = () => mock;
  }
}

export const ObjectFactory = {
  getInstance<T>(name: string): T {
    return Factory.getInstance(name) as T;
  },

  mockWithInstance: Factory.mockWithInstance,
};

const impl = ObjectFactory.getInstance<SomeInterface>("SomeInterface");
```

As you can see, this Factory lets you instantiation and mocking of those interfaces. The main problem is that I have to call this function with the name of the interface AND the interface to keep the type in the assignments:

```js
ObjectFactory.getInstance<SomeInterface>("SomeInterface")
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634116/factory-returning-classes-in-typescript), but I do not like the idea of using a `Base` interface. Moreover, that approach does not keep the type neither.

Ideally, I would want to use my approach but without having to use the interface, that is, use only the name of the interface.

Side note: the declaration of `Injectable` is a hack to make that code work, ideally, I would like to be able to use only the implementation name, that is:

```js
let DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS = {
    SomeInterface: Implementation
}
```

Comment: are the list of interfaces known at compile time?  Or do you add new ones over time?  I wish the code here were a [mcve] where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about, with some lines showing expected-vs-actual behavior.  Right now in order to play with this I have to deal with whatever `ConcreteImplementation` is and I don't see the use cases in the code.

Comment: I have edited the example, in case you need more information, I have reduced the use case from my university project where I am trying to create a parser using clean architecture: https://github.com/antoniogamiz/manga-api/blob/master/src/modules/common/factories/ObjectFactory.ts .

Comment: You could possibly use assertion functions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMnZW) to "dynamically" add interfaces to the list, but it is more complicated and brittle than just using a fixed list

Comment: Those edits make things [worse](https://tsplay.dev/Lw67YN), as they have syntax errors (curly quotes are not valid) and other problems (`new Implementation()` is not a valid `() => unknown`, there's no function named `getInstance()`).  Please consider putting example code into an IDE and testing its behavior before posting it.  I have to disengage for now, but my question remains: do you need to be able to *add* interfaces via `mockWithInstance()`, or do you just use a *fixed list of existing interfaces*?  The former is possible-ish with assertion functions, but the latter is much easier.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's fixed now. Yes, I use a fixed list of existing interfaces. I import them and add them like SomeInterface.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/nWPyqw) work for you? If so I'll write it up. If not, please edit the question/elaborate.

Comment: lol, that's pretty awesome!! It works!! :oo Thanks a lot, it's pretty advanced so I do not understand a lot of it, I'm looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a fixed list of name-to-type mappings you care about supporting, the general approach here is to think in terms of the object type `T` representing this mapping, and then for any supported interface name `K extends keyof T`, you will be dealing with functions that return the property at that name... namely, functions of type `() => T[K]`.  Another way to say this is that we will be using [`keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to help give types to your factory.

We will only be using a concrete type like `{"SomeInterface": SomeInterface; "Date": Date}` for `T`, but in what follows the compiler has an easier time of things if `T` is generic.  Here's a possible generic implementation of an `ObjectFactory` maker:

```
function makeFactory<T>(DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS: { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] }) {
  const MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS: { [K in keyof T]?: () => T[K] } = {};
  return {
    getInstance<K extends keyof T>(interfaceName: K) {
      const compositeInjectable: typeof DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS = {
        ...DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS,
        ...MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS
      };
      return compositeInjectable[interfaceName]();
    },
    mockWithInstance<K extends keyof T>(interfaceName: K, mock: T[K]) {
      MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS[interfaceName] = () => mock;
    }
  }
}
```

I refactored your version into something the compiler can mostly verify as type safe, so as to avoid [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Let's walk through it.

The `makeFactory` function is generic in the object mapping type `T`, and takes an argument named `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS` of type `{ [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] }`.  This is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) whose keys `K` are the same as those of `T` but whose properties are zero-arg functions that return a value of type `T[K]`.  You can see how your existing `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS` was like this: each property was a zero-arg function returning a value of the corresponding interface.

Inside the function implementation, we create `MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS`.  This variable has almost the same type as `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS` but with the properties being *optional* (as effected by the optionality modifier `?` in `[K in keyof T]?`).

The function returns the factory itself, which has two methods:

The `getInstance` method is generic in `K`, the type of the interface name, and the return value is of type `T[K]`, the corresponding interface property.  I implement this by merging `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS` and `MOCK_IMPLEMENTATIONS` via [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), and annotating that this `compositeInjectable` is the same type as `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS`.  Then we index into it with the `interfaceName` and call it.

The `mockWithInstance` method is also generic in `K`, the type of the interface name, and accepts a parameter of type `K` (the interface name), and a parameter of type `T[K]` (the corresponding interface).

---

Let's see it in action:

```
const ObjectFactory = makeFactory({
  SomeInterface: (): SomeInterface => new Implementation(),
  Date: () => new Date()
});

console.log(ObjectFactory.getInstance("SomeInterface").get().toUpperCase()); // HEY :D
ObjectFactory.mockWithInstance("SomeInterface", { get: () => "howdy" });
console.log(ObjectFactory.getInstance("SomeInterface").get().toUpperCase()); // HOWDY
console.log(ObjectFactory.getInstance("Date").getFullYear()); // 2020
```

This all works as I think you expect.  We make `ObjectFactory` by calling `makeFactory` with the desired `DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATIONS` object.  Here I have annotated that the `SomeInterface` property returns a value of type `SomeInterface` (otherwise the compiler would infer `Implementation` which may be more specific than you'd like).

Then we can see that the compiler lets us call `ObjectFactory.getInstance()` and `ObjectFactory.mockWithInstance()` with the proper arguments and returning the expected types, and it also works at runtime.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAxV04BOAngDwAqAfABQAiAotgIICqAMmQPoCSAsgAqs6POgDkyjMlwDyIgMoAuRAG9EAbQDSiGEixE4wRGQC6iqgEpEAXgqGNRxAF8LSgLAAoRIggIAzlEQ8UgDC6tz8gsJiEtJyiioaWjqYegbGAPymFta26vYOVsoOANzungSYUCAESK4enogA5hVcYH6okJgkmpgAHlCYYAAmPoi6+obU2v0EwHiYIqjImIrqzqX1nt6t-t7IAA5wPjD9LQBWmNCoAEYANsuIUER7mOP0TGycvAJCouKSMrICrUNhsAHTgt4sdhhb6RP4xWQAGnWIMQ4NBgRCMIiv2iAJR9WKBLKFSqSF2ByOJzA50ut0wqimmBmcwWSyM5hKdU8DmR3JQcAg6AA6scABYtNodLqIXr9IYjMapSZgaazCDzRb3dSIgVCxRkOxrfmeTGhL44qL-OSM1XM9Wa9kFcxWGzIQXoLkbBzrH1uP3uJksjWIWRwJYtNVzZTrJpQcyKPwEbQNLkBtwQG6oHwjLj7O5LVWoWAILT5zCFqAjMMRu3BzAxupbJMgfAEF0qP2eOMdgnlSrVRAAIgAEslEPIaEOvY53Onm-4pFdaVBcG2iAU0Fg11BCEQqMDQ+HMJH7XNMooaye6w7XYgwJgAO6IPN7AsDKDF+Bgcx8zw0Yt7hdbIH2fAD+nMOczC5dxmzgO5QRuOAGioJcVx3PdQTjSVPw6KghyvU96yHMwsIqcxQV3Zg9meAggmzTBzGgxAAHoWMQEc6AATQnGh3DQi5VzwXdiFBd0hVFKAJW2doNXwwibzmIddRUONMjvIcxTgR9BiIIdHGg2DfHgzBEOQ1Dl0EjDROwmS8II48iIdEiyPjUiqJo5l6J8RizGYtiOKkYUaC4ozWhMsyUIE6BrKIVycNkxih3AzAXLjbAQBuG4uMwVB2z8opWPYgAmAAGMqgA)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your incredible answer. I just want to know if it’s possible to get rid of the SomeInterface: () => new SomeImplementation() hack. I mean, declare the available interfaces as SomeInterface: SomeImplementation and create them in the makeFactory function.

Comment: You're the one who wrote `SomeInterface: () => new Implementation()` in the example code so I'm not sure how it's a hack exactly?  Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ymAZvW) maybe?  If not, please elaborate, but keep in mind that this might be outside the scope of this question as asked and not amenable to further discussion here.

Comment: That is a hack because I had to do it to make my old solution works :/. What I mean is just using { SomeInterface: SomeImplementation} as argument to the makeFactory function. Sorry for that, I should have said that was a hack in the question.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question, but it was my fault so feel free to ignore my request, you have already helped me a lot.